# sqlite retrieving items from table containing string in field

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve items from a SQLite db table in Python where there is a match in a particular field. In other words if I search for `'rabbit'` I want to retrieve all entries that have the string `'rabbit'` in a particular column. My code looks like this:

Python server code for endpoint:

```
          if self.path=='/getOne':
             form = cgi.FieldStorage(
             fp=self.rfile, 
             headers=self.headers,
             environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
             'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
        })

        value = []
        for key in form.keys():
            value.append("%" + form.getvalue(key) + "%")
            print 'LOOK my value', value

        c.execute('select * from appointments where description=?' , value)
        res = c.fetchall()
        # _json = json.dumps(res)
        # print 'This is res from _get_all_appts', res
        # print 'From line 18:  ', _json
        # self.wfile.write(_json)
        print "I'm ya huckleberry", res
    return
```

What is printing in console:

```
    From line 18:   [["15:01", "asdf", "2020-05-07"], ["14:01", "test", 
    "2020-04-04"]]
    LOOK my value ['%test%']
    I'm ya huckleberry []
    LOOK my value ['%test%']
    I'm ya huckleberry []
```

As you can see what is printing out on line 18 are the entries on my table.
My value `['%test%]` should return the second entry since I want to return any entry that contains the string `test` in that particular column but I get nothing. I come from a JS background and would easily do this with string interpolation/template strings. Is there anything anyone can suggest that would help bring the desired effect? I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer to your first part of the question, the `LIKE` operator might do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM appointments
WHERE description LIKE '%rabbit%';
```

If this does not meet your expectations, then you could try looking into full text search with SQLite.  One reason the above query might fall short for you is that it would match the substring `rabbit` occurring anywhere.  For example, it would also match `rabbits`.  Full text search would get around most of these edge cases.

To make the term inside the `LIKE` expression dynamic, you would use Python code along these lines:

```
param = 'rabbit'
t = ('%'+param+'%',)
c.execute('select * from appointments where description like ?', t)
c.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I dug through stackoverflow and saw a similar example. That doesn't work because it is hard coded and I am going for a dynamic approach where the user would enter a search term on the front and it would then be passed to the back. That like operator is no where in pythons documentation by the way. And yes, I have tried it in several variations `like` that is. I do appreciate your input though and thank you for your time. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: @str8up7od I updated my answer with some sample Python code using `LIKE`.  It _is_ possible to search based on a parameter.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, Thank you! I am on track and debugging other issues now. you have been great!